# Plane not visible in Hierarchy

Tags: geometry

I want to add a plane as shown [in this video](https://youtu.be/Qp9aGui2Cks?t=220).
In this video (please watch it at 0.25 speed), the author creates a plane.
His plane appears upright, and it is shown in the Hierarchy.

I do the same, but my plane lays flat on the floor and doesn't appear in the Hierarchy.

What am I doing differently than he does?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're creating the plane in edit mode, and therefore it's just adding to your cube object (hence why it's not appearing in the heirarchy). Planes come "flat" (X/Y axis aligned) by default (in both object and edit mode) - just rotate it in edit mode by 90 degrees.

Comment: @Carlo It doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Don't know why that is. Maybe some preset they saved. Every time I add a plane, it is always "flat".  ALSO - sorry about my first (misleading) comment - I meant to say you were adding in edit mode - adding it in object mode is the correct way. I corrected my first comment to reflect this.

Comment: "        ,         ". As @ChristopherBennett said, creating a plane in EDIT mode as you are doing add the mesh to the current object (cube.001). So as the linked answer explain, you are not creating a new object. You should create it in OBJECT mode, and though it's fast, it is being rotate 90 deg on x axis, you can see it written in the lower left in this frame: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wry96.png

Comment: @Carlo I find my question more distinct, so I would to keep my own question open if possible.

Comment: No problem with that. I was only pointing toward an already well made answer that was adressing your problem so you didn't have to wait for one.